# Django Python does not display the correct PDF file

Tags: python, django, pdf

I have PDF files which are stored on the server. I am writing a code which prompts users to download the PDF file. I used the following code:

```
filename ="somepdf.pdf"
filedir = "media/"
filepath = os.path.join( filedir, filename )

pdf=open(filepath)
response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(),content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=%s' % filename
return response
```

For some reason, I rechecked the PDF file that was prompted. The PDF file are not readable (corrupted file perhaps).

Do you know what happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed MEDIA_ROOT:

```
from settings import MEDIA_ROOT
...
filepath = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, filedir, filename)
```

Comment: Of course, MEDIA_ROOT should be properly configured.

Comment: `filepath = os.path.join( filedir, filename )` should work withour using MEDIA_ROOT. I think the question is not about MEDIA_ROOT but why the opened data are somehow corrupted.

Comment: Igor and Normal, thanks for your answers. However, it has not resolved the issues yet

Igor, where should I put your code? I tried at views.py but it gives me error. (no module named settings)

Norman, I suspect that it did not serve the right PDF, even though it looks like it. When I comes back and check on the PDF, it shows up just fine on my computer. Perhaps there is some misinterpretation when Django tries to serve the PDF

Answer (score 0):

I found what the answer is.

Apparently the Media_ROOT and Media_URL doesn't work in my case. I use the web browsing debugging tool and locate the discrepancy between the link and the actual PDF.

It should be "/media/" not "media"

I used this code in the HTML to serve the file:

```
   <embed height="100%" width="100%" name="plugin" src="/media/receipts/Receipt_1.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```